# samplepdf.tex will not compile

Tags: pdftex

According to the pdfTeX manual (p. 7), "A more thorough and descriptive test is the plain TeX test file samplepdf.tex, available in the distribution in the samplepdftex/ directory." I found it, copied it to another directory, applied `gunzip`, and tried `pdftex`. However, that gave an error. Here is the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdftex 2020.7.13)  24 APR 2021 15:59
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**samplepdf
(./samplepdf.tex (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftex/pdfcolor.tex
){/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map} [1] [2
Position: X=4736286sp, Y=28455731sp.
! pdfTeX error (ext5): cannot open file for embedding.
\plainoutput ...headline \pagebody \makefootline }
                                                  \advancepageno \ifnum \out...
<output> {\plainoutput 
                       }
\break ->\penalty -\@M 
                       
l.481 \newpage
              

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

What is wrong? (In general, `pdftex` works fine.)

Comment: it looks like you are missing `obj.dat` at least, compare with the log I just posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried it in texlive 2021 and it runs without error. Did you copy the entire directory?

```
$ pdftex samplepdf
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./samplepdf.tex (./pdfcolor.tex){/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/p
dftex/updmap/pdftex.map} [1] [2
Position: X=4736286sp, Y=28455731sp.
<<obj.dat>><<obj.dat>><<obj.dat>>] [3 <./pic.pdf> <./pic.pdf> <./pic.png> <./pi
c.pdf>]<<rgb.icc>> (./supp-mis.tex
loading : Context Support Macros / Miscellaneous (2004.10.26)
) (./supp-pdf.tex
loading : Context Support Macros / PDF (2004.03.26)
) [4 <./pic16.png> <./pic.jpg> <./pic.jpg>] [MP to PDF] (./samplepdf.0)
[MP to PDF] (./samplepdf.1) [5] [6 <./tmp.pdf>] [7] [8] [9] [10] [11] )</usr/lo
cal/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmb10.pfb></usr/loca
l/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb></usr/local
/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/t
exlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb></usr/local/te
xlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt10.pfb>
Output written on samplepdf.pdf (11 pages, 933418 bytes).
Transcript written on samplepdf.log.
```

Comment: No, I had not. That was the problem. It now works fine for me. Thanks!